# A fixed max size container class containing unique elements with functions like push_back and pop_back and is iterate-able

Tags: c++, stack

```
template <class T, int max_size>
class FixedSizedUniqueStack
{
    std::vector<T> m_vec;
    std::unordered_set<T> m_uset;
public:
    FixedSizedUniqueStack():m_vec(max_size){}
    bool push(T& x)
    {
        bool success = true;
        if(m_uset.insert(x)) m_vec.push_back(x);
        else success = false;
        return success;
    }
    void pop()
    {
        if(m_vec.size() > 0)
        {
            m_uset.erase(m_vec.back());
            m_vec.pop_back();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please make the title be a ... *title*. Post your information about the code in the body of the question, covering your concerns which the answers will talk about.

Comment: This question could really use some description about the problem you are trying to solve. Try to give people a little bit of context about the code you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Duplicate value storage:

One disadvantage of your approach is that it stores a duplicate of each value inserted. The cost can become prohibitive for large objects, such as class instances stored by value.

A possible approach to avoid the duplicate would be just doing a linear search over the vector every time a new insertion takes place. For small arrays, this is usually quite fast.

Another possible implementation would be to keep the vector always sorted, then a fast binary search could be performed before insertions to ensure uniqueness.

#### Proper way of testing `set/map` insertion:

This code doesn't seem correct:

> ```
>     bool success = true;
>     if(m_uset.insert(x)) m_vec.push_back(x);
>     else success = false;
>     return success;
> ```

The `insert` method of sets and maps of the Standard Library will return you *a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place* ([from here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert)).

So the correct way to test if the insertion was successful would be:

```
if (m_uset.insert(value).second == true)
{
    ...
}
```

#### `max_size` is never checked:

You've stated in the title that the container should have a fixed maximum size, however, you never check to see if the limit size was reached. `push_back` in a vector will resize the container if its initial capacity is exceeded. Same is true for `set::insert`.

#### `push()` is taking a mutable reference, which can cause confusion:

The signature of `bool push(T& x)`, taking a mutable reference to `T`, shows the called that this method has the intention or possibility of altering the input parameter. That would be a pretty strange behaviour for a container. When storing some data, you don't want it to be changed by the container. The proper signature here would be to pass the value by **const reference**:

```
bool push(const T& x);
```

That will prevent a copy and will pass a clear message to the caller that the input value is not changed, only stored.

As you polish this interface, you should consider [move semantics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) (C++11), and add a move reference (`T&&`) overload for `push()`.

#### `empty()` is a more idiomatic way of checking for empty containers:

The traditional way of testing if a Standard container is empty is by calling the [`empty()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/empty) method, as opposed to `if (c.size() > 0)`.